# Multipart\form data in a XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: java, servlets, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I am trying to send both text and files to a Java Servlet. This worked fine when working on the same server, but now I"m getting Cross-Domain access issues.

I've set the headers in the servlets and this generally works when sending plain text, but the one section where I have to send a file thought a multipart\form data is still giving me the **"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."** error. So somewhere I need to set the headers to accommodate the form data, but the other pages and tutorials only seem to say what the header should look like, not how to set it. Here is my code:

**Upload.js**

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("id", fA[0].name.split('.')[0]);
fd.append("frame", fA[0].size);
fd.append('file', fA[0]);
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://myserver:myport/Upload", true);
var sBoundary = "---------------------------" + Date.now().toString(16);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart\/form-data; boundary=" + sBoundary);
request.send(fd);
```

**Upload.java**

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
            //the rest of my code
 }
```

Comment: Have you checked the response headers and you’re not seeing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` etc in the response from the servlet?

Comment: I don't think it's that line, for the reason that if I take out the part of the data that handles the multipart form data I'm able to get responses back. It's probably on the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" line, or on client side when I'm making the request.

Comment: I was asking about the HTTP response, not any of those lines. The only reason you would get that "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." message is if the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is not getting sent in the response. I suggested you check the response, to see if there header were there or not, but I guess you understand already it’s not there. There is nothing on the client side that would affect this. The server would be sending the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response regardless of anything you did on the client side.

Comment: So, I think you were right. I got it fixed by moving the response out of the try\catch block. Apparently inside the try\catch it didn't see the response headers I set.